# Prevent multiple sql job calls from API/code

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, api, asp.net-web-api, jobs

I have an application which calls an API on button click. The API executes an SP which runs a job to perform some operations.

**Issue**: In case of many clients, multiple clicks can go from front end which might result in calling of API's multiple times and execution of SP each time. This results in running of same sql job more than once which is wrong.

**What I have done:** To prevent this, I have modified the SP to check if the job is running then wait else run the job.

**How its behaving:** If I call API multiple times(using multiple tabs) using Postman, the job is called only once, which is correct. If I execute the SP after giving the required parameters multiple times (from several clients), the job executes only once. But if I make button clicks from several clients in one go, the job would run for each click (which is wrong).

Please let me know if anyone can help me on this. Maybe you might know another way to debug or test this scenario.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you prevent button double click?

Comment: Its not a double click from one client, its clicks from multiple clients pointing to same server db.

Comment: Then What I believe is there must be a issue with your Job / SP. Then what I understood is you don't want to run your job each and every click But It needs to be run once for each click (Globally).  Is that it?

Comment: I ran that SP(with proper parameters) in multiple tabs in Sql server simultaneously, but the job ran only once (which is correct). So I think the SP is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `OutputCacheAttribute` on the Web API Method call which would just return the last response until it expires. This would mean the method would never execute if within the cache duration regardless of how many times the API method was called.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx